# Not able to publish Binary component in Tridion with specific file name in Chinese

Tags: binary, deployer

I am not able to publish PDF files with filename 金融机构客户身份识别和客户身份资料及交易管理办公室备存纪录

I am getting the below error in committing deployment phase

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed. Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-21624-66560

I am getting below error in deployer logs

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: String or binary data would be truncated.
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3006) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2908) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3237) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:59) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1053) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1108) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

Please advise .

Comment: Just to add on the above question ,I think the issue is with the size of column "URL" in BINARYVARIANTS table .I am still debugging this .

Answer (score 1):

Deployer saves the URL in URLEncoded format and if the length of that exceeds 255(default size of column length) you will see this error. I believe that's what exactly happening in your case, if you try URL encode of your filename it is 262 chars. I suggest you open a support ticket for resolution which could be increasing the column length higher than 255 to suitable length.

Alternately, you could trim the image path during the publish using the resolver or TBB by checking the length of url encoded image path (little tricky.. also you might not have a proper image path..)